# Loop checking convention

Tags: c++, loops, convention

If I was going through a loop, say iterating a vector, and I don't want to do an action on some item in the vector, I can do it in two ways:

This is the one I prefer to use:

```
vector<int> vec;
void loopFunction(int toIgnore) {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < vec.size(); index++) {
        if (vec[index] == toIgnore) continue;
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This is the one I see most people use:

```
vector<int> vec;
void loopFunction(int toIgnore) {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < vec.size(); index++) {
        if (vec[index] != toIgnore) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I know in the final results there is absolutely no difference. However, is there any difference under the hood since the second way opens a new scope to execute? Is any of these two preferred over the other?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid as much embedded scoping as I can so I could go with the first example using `continue` so that everything within the loop is on the same level. All about preference though. There's no performance advantage for either as far as i know

Comment: I also prefer the first way to do it. I do not like nested scopes in my code as well. However, does adding a new scope add an overhead or not? I think it might for large loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, on a personal level, I prefer the first implementation using `continue` in order to prevent unnecessary code nesting and scope creation.

The only performance overhead from each, in addition to the normal code that will be implemented, is the evaluation of the expression in the `if-statement`. Since they both contain an expression to be evaluated, they're the same performance wise.

If you think about how this is compiled, for C/C++, its straight into assembly code. On that level no matter how you nest the code, it compiles into simple `jmp` and `cmp` commands. Therefore, regardless of the implementation, on compile, you'll have the ~same assembly code.

Either way you look at it, this is a micro-micro-micro optimization, if at all! Do what you prefer for code formatting and styling.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I shall then stick with the first format, looks more neat :p

Comment: I did performance tests for huge vectors and yeah they produced similar results. Moreover, I did tests on C# and got the same results, so they really make no difference. Just preference